# CFDictionaryValueCallBacks retain/release?

Tags: objective-c, core-foundation

Is there a constant retain callback I can use for generic `id` / `NSObject`s ? There is `kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks` but they're only for "CFType-derived objects." I don't believe NSObjects are CFTypes, so I wrote these:

```
const void *valueRetainCallBack(CFAllocatorRef allocator, const void *ptr)
{
    id o = (id)ptr;
    [o retain];

    return o;
}

void valueReleaseCallBack(CFAllocatorRef allocator, const void *ptr)
{
    id o = (id)ptr;
    [o release];
}
```

But perhaps there is a simpler way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a constant retain callback I can use for generic id / NSObjects ? There is `kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks` but they're only for "CFType-derived objects." I don't believe NSObjects are CFTypes…

They're not documented as fully bridged, but for memory management (retain and release), [that's documented to work](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CarbonCocoaDoc/Articles/InterchangeableDataTypes.html). In practice, all the functions common to CFType and NSObject, including `description`/`CFCopyDescription`, work as well.